# update column of second table by column of first table using update query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Table ep1

```
ID | NAME

1  | mohit

2  | rohit

3  | rohit

4  | vikram

5  | ankur
```

Table ep2

```
 NAME  | ID

mohit  | -

rohit  | -

rohit  | -

vikram |-

ankur  | -
```

I want to fill id column of ep2 from ep1. I am using this query: `update ep2 set id=(select id from ep1 where name=ep2.name)`, but I not able to get the desired output because there are two persons with same name in table ep1.

Comment: do you have any more data in `EP2` table or only 1 column? If that is the case just truncate the table and insert all data from `ep1`

Comment: Is this ep2 already created? If not you could simple do: `INSERT INTO ep2 (NAME,ID) SELECT NAME,ID FROM ep1;` That is if  the table doesn't contain any data otherwise it will append ep2. However, I would not recommend  this approach because I will leave you with duplication of data, because the names will then be in two tables. I recommend to transfer only the IDs to ep2.

Comment: ep2 is already created but i want to transfer id according to the name of the person even if we change the order of name in ep2

Comment: @user3334145 in that case I think this cannot be done. How would you know which rohit has ID 2 and who has 3? Especially if you would change the order of the names in ep2. Or is there a way you could identify which rohit is which?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a common ID between the two tables, you could do this:

```
Update t2  
SET name = t1.name 
FROM  ep2  t2 
INNER JOIN ep1 t1  ON t1.ID= t2.Id and t2.ID= someIdValue
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply 
I want to fill out id column not the name column.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update e2
set id = e1.id
from ep1 as e1
 inner join ep2 as e2
   on e1.name = e2.name
where e2.id is null
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and why it works by [edit]ing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Update ep2
SET id = ep1.id 
FROM  ep2  
INNER JOIN ep1  ON ep1.name= ep2.name
```